# Do I need permission from motorsports organisations to write a research paper about motor racing?

Tags: publications, research-topic

I have written a research paper analysing the aerodynamics of racing cars in a particular motor sport as a hobby project (using my own 3D model and resources). However, now I’m beginning to question if it is required of me to seek permission from that particular motorsports organisation (ie. F1 or NASCAR) before writing and publishing this research paper? Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you use any data from the organizations (or any external souce) in your work, you would need to check that you comply with the license / terms of use at least.

Comment: From where did you obtain the 3d model?

Comment: This cannot be answered in a useful way without reading your paper, but the answer is probably no.

Answer (score 1):

You only need permission to talk about something if you use information you have gotten from someone for which they own the intellectual property (copyright). I specifically say "talk" because writing a research paper is, in some sense, still speech.

In other words, if all you have used in your paper is publicly available information, then you don't need written approval. If you have used a computational geometry in your work that you have obtained from someone else who has intellectual property ownership over it, then you do need approval.

Comment: This is wrong.  Publicly available information may be protected by copyright.  Data is not protected in some jurisdictions.  https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/11359/can-you-copyright-data  You do not need permission to critique copyrighted materials in some jurisdictions.